# jQuery resize plugin on divs

Tags: jquery, html, plugins, resize

I have been looking at this plug-in http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/examples/resize/ and can make it work fine with the example for displaying the dimensions of the window.

I want to display the dimensions of a specific div, when I try to do this the dimensions are displayed when the page loads but do not change as the div is resized by changing the browser window.

**I'm using this code:**

```
// Bind the resize event. When the window size changes, update its corresponding
// info div.
$('.main').resize(function(){
    var elem = $(this);

    // Update the info div width and height 
    $('#main-dim').text( 'Main, width: ' + elem.width() + ', height: ' + elem.height() );
});

// Updates the info div immediately.
$('.main').resize();

});
```

`.main` is the div I want to get the dimensions on, `#main-dim` is the div to display the dimensions in.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Surround your code between the document ready block:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
     // add code here
  });
</script>
```